# Python find out records in dataframe by column values greater than or equal to their median in each subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

suppose I have  a dataframe  which could  be initiated by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['1','2','3','4','5','6'],
                   'group2': ['c','c','d','d','d','e'],
                   'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'value2': [7.1,8,9,10,11,12]
                   })
df = df.set_index(['group1', 'group2'])
```

I want to subset `df` by the `value2` column, the value of which is greater or equal to the median of each sub-group specified by the index of `group2`. In this example, the row of `group1` in `['2','4','5','6']` should stay in the result. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df['value2'] = df['value2'].groupby(level='group2').transform(lambda x: np.where(x>=np.median(x), x, np.NaN))
df = df.dropna()
```

What this does is it gets the `value2` column, and splits it into groups by `group2`.  For each group, it finds the median, then replaces and value below the median with `NaN`.  It then puts this back into the `value2` column, then gets rid of all the rows with `NaN` values.

As an alternative, here is a slightly less clear one-liner:

```
df = df.groupby(level='group2').transform(lambda x: x if x.name != 'group2' else np.where(x>=np.median(x), x, np.NaN)).dropna()
```

This does roughly the same thing, except it runs on both columns, but doesn't do anything to the `group1` column.

Note that in the second approach you could instead store to a second variable, like `df2`, without altering the original `df` if you prefer.  You could do that with the first approach, but that would require yet another line to make a copy.  This version is much simpler for that case.

Comment: The second example does not appear to change df.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a groupby and comparison before setting the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['1','2','3','4','5','6'],
                   'group2': ['c','c','d','d','d','e'],
                   'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'value2': [7.1,8,9,10,11,12]
                   })
gb = df.groupby('group2').value2.median()
df.join(gb, on='group2', rsuffix='_median')
df_filtered = df[df.value2 >= df.join(gb, on='group2', rsuffix='_median').value2_median]
df_filtered.set_index(['group1', 'group2'], inplace=True)
>>> df_filtered 
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
2      c            2       8
4      d            4      10
5      d            5      11
6      e            6      12
```